# @TypeDef(typeClass = PostgreSQLIntervalType.class, defaultForType = Duration.class) annotation in Hibernate 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I updated hibernate to version 6, but it turned out that the @TypeDef annotation was removed.
Annotation:

```
@TypeDef(
        typeClass = PostgreSQLIntervalType.class,
        defaultForType = Duration.class)
```

Field:

```
    @Column(name = "period", columnDefinition = "interval")
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Duration workedOutTime = Duration.between(createdAt.toLocalTime(), createdAt.toLocalTime());

    public LocalTime getWorkedOutTime() {
        return LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(workedOutTime.getSeconds());
    }

    public long getWorkedOutDuration() {
        return workedOutTime.getSeconds();
    }
```

How can it be replaced?

Comment: If it is deprecated, it will have documentation how to replace it (and besides, it will still work if it was only deprecated).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was wrong, this annotation has already been removed in Hibernate 6.

Comment: The Hibernate 6 documentation and Migration Guide really gloss over this (as in hardly describe this, they just mention it was removed). I think [this example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-bitset) might show you the alternative, but I'm not entirely sure.